# firebase get data for specific user

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am trying to build a webapp like an agenda that keeps a list of contacts for each user. So each user can have it's own contacts list and the issue is when i log with a specific user i want to show only the contacts that this user has.

```
firebase.database().ref('contacts').orderByChild('uid').equalTo(uid).once('value')


contacts/
    contact-id
        firstName
        lastName
        uid
```

This is what i use right now, uid being the id of the logged user.
Is there a better way to do this ?
thank you in advance, Daniel!

Comment: What is `contact-id`?

Answer (score 0):

Structure your database like this:

```
users: {
    user1: {
        name: "User 1",
        contacts: {
            contact1: true,
            contact2: true
        }
    },
    user2: {
        name: "User 2",
        contacts: {
            contact1: true,
            contact3: true
        }
    }
}
```

Replace user1, user 2 with UID.

and contacts:

```
contacts: {
    contact1: {
        name: "Contact 1",
        mobile: 00000
    },
    contact2: {
        name: "Contact 2",
        mobile: 11111
    },
    contact3: {
        name: "Contact 3",
        mobile: 22222
    }
}
```

Now the moment someone logs in, you will get the current uid and you can use it find out the contact list of the currently logged in user.

```
firebase.database().ref('users/'+userUID+'/contacts').on('child_added', snapshot => {
  firebase.database().ref('contacts/'+snapshot.key).on('value', snap => {
    console.log(snap.val().name); //Print name of persons in contact list
  });
});
```